# How can I connect a potentiometer to the solenoid?

Tags: potentiometer

I have done a bit of research but cannot find anything hard and fast describing what I am trying to do.

I have a solenoid in the steering rack of my racing car.  This solenoid is controlled by the ECU and varies the amount of power steering the rack receives using a solenoid. As the car goes faster it gets less power steering.  This is unnerving on track and not optimal.

I would like to manually control the voltage input to the solenoid from inside the car. Solenoid input voltage specs below

- Maximum (highest power steering) 5.5V @ 1.1A
- Minimum (least power steering) 2.1V @ 0.4A

The car supplies 14.9V with the engine running.

I figure I can wire in a toggle switch.  When off the ECU circuit is connected and the car runs as intended.  When switch on the circuit runs through the potentiometer.

- Potentiometer specs are 20 ohm 0.125W @ 350V AC
- 12V switching voltage @ 1.5A

[image]

I have drawn up a small schematic but I do not think it is correct.  With the specified potentiometer and a 30 ohm resistor before it I can vary the output voltage between 6V and 1.2V which should be sufficient.

Is this correct or am I way off?

Comment: If the solenoid requires up to 1.1**A**  then your resistive divider of 30K and 20K is completely incapable of providing this by a factor of about 2,000. Even omitting the 20K pot, you could only get about 0.5**mA** at the most via a 30K resistor. If you did build a resistive divider then the upper resistor would need to be around 8 ohms (again ignoring the pot) and be capable of dissipating 10W. It gets a lot worse once you factor in the pot. At one point you do say it's a 30 ohm resistor and 20 ohm pot but rated at 0.125W which is far too low. I suggest you look at a different method.

Comment: Using resistor divider for such current is not suitable. You should explore other possibilities like using an adjustable voltage regulator or a buck converter.

Comment: are you certain that the device is a solenoid? ... from the description, it seems to be a linear motor

Comment: @jsotola Yeah, solenoids are either ON or OFF, which means he'd only need a manual override switch if he that were the case. This is NOT a solenoid! We need a part # on the device he's trying to control.

Answer (score 1):

Solenoid force is related to current, so you can get by with a resistance in series.  The resistor has to handle some power, so I wouldn't use a potentiometer because it might fail with unpredictable results. It could theoretically work if you found one that could handle the power.  You can treat your solenoid as a 5-ohm resistor.

If you can determine what current you like, I think your best bet would be a fixed resistor with a value between 8 and 32 ohms.  It will have to handle the power, at least 15 watts.  I put in a catch diode which should be rated at 2 amps.  I also added a second switch to allow you to disconnect the ECU prior to changing states, but this might not be necessary if you have a break-before-make switch.  I would never try to switch states when you're in motion.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIO1UJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>